# Should I build server-side of application inside nuxt.js server directory?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, project, nuxt.js

I want to build full-stack application with **Nuxt.js**. I am wondering where I should create my server-side inside **Nuxt.js** or maybe I should create separated project only for server stuff.

I am trying to set up my project but I do not know how I should do it. The application which I am building will have own front-end, back-end and also database (I will use **MongoDB**) but actually I do not know how I should start. I was reading a lot about SSR and **Nuxt.js** seems really good if am planing to use **Vue.js** on fronted. While creating nuxt app I can choose to use Express and then I can see server directory inside my directory structure does it mean that i should build all back-end inside this directory or maybe it is only for small stuff?
I have also another question what if I want to use `Nest.js` on back-end can i just use `npm i -g @nestjs/cli` and then `nest new project-name` inside my server directory ? I was looking also for this answer but almost all results in google for this type are about (comparison between **Nuxt.js**, **Next.js** and **Nest.js**).

It will be my first bigger full-stack project and I want to do it right but I am a really beginner in this so I am looking for answer from more experienced programmers.

Comment: btw these sort of questions really are better suited for the software engineering SE

Comment: Has there been any more thought about this type of Solution. A "Monolith" app on nuxt.js with async server/client logic and then server only business logic (Auth, etc) as well as database access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run express or any node.js server you want **inside** Nuxt.js. When installing Nuxt.js with scaffolding tool [create-nuxt-app](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation#using-code-create-nuxt-app-code-), you can choose integrated server-side frameworks : Express, Koa, Hapi, Feathers, Micro, Fastify, Adonis (WIP). There isn't offical Nest.js integration, but [you can easily find a starter kit on github](https://github.com/search?q=nuxt+nest).

With `create-nuxt-app`, if you choose to use any node.js server **inside** your nuxt app, you will see a `server` directory inside your directory structure, with the corresponding server-side pre-configured `index.js` file.

Here is my *own* feeling about it:

I think the inside solution make sense for a small SPA or Headless project (Ex: parse and serve files, a simple JWT Authentification, a small websocket server...), or for a front-end logic application that cannot fit in client browser and who are nothing to do with the database (like image or file computation).
But generally, this server run the database layer for your Nuxt application: a REST or GraphQL API. It can also run your business logic of your app, serve authentification, and more and more when project growth...

> If you think about separation of concerns and microservices
>   architecture, **do not use server inside** Nuxt.js. Splitting both frontend and server will result more flexibility. You can host frontend and API in different servers.

So now, **do nuxt.js really need a node.js server ?**
Yes if you plan to use it in SSR mode, No if you plan to use it like a SPA or Static generated way. [Docs here...](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#single-page-applications-spa-) .
In SSR mode, nuxt.js ask data to your API at the first rendering, and provide a complete SEO compatible page to the client browser or bots. It also provide all javascript that the browser need to navigate and fetch your API. For that, nuxt.js in SSR mode should run with node.js.

I assume you said "back-end" for your API and your business logic application, in this case, you should separate nuxt.js and your server. Two node.js instances to run both.

Comment: I think the same about API and having indpendent fronted and backedn, but there is one isue, what about SSR, can I have without **Nuxt.js** ? Or maybe it is good idea to use **Nux.js** to build SPA application (in documentation we can read that it is also solving SEO problems)? And what do you mean by this ```"not good to group folder structure if you plan to split nuxt and server in different servers"```