# Is it required to use server folder in Nuxt 3 when we have API endpoints?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

We have a `server` folder in Nuxt 3. It has an `api` folder. why we should use it when we have API endpoints using a server-side programming language? are they related together or not?
for example, we have these endpoints that have been created using Laravel:

```
 http://www.example.com/product
 http://www.example.com/product/1
```

We can call these endpoints using `useFetch` or `$fetch` so we can use their data. is it required to use `server/api` folder here?
for example, we have these folders and files:

```
server/api/product/index.get.ts
server/api/product/[productId]/index.get.ts
```

Can you help me? are they related together or not? which time we should use the `server` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different approaches to using APIs with Nuxt. If you're developing a full-stack application where the frontend and backend are tightly coupled, creating the endpoints directly in the server directory would make sense.

If in your case you have a separate frontend and backend. Then using the server directory would be unnecessary. It could be nice if you want to create a simple endpoint directly tied to the Nuxt app. A use case might be the authentication/authorization from a security standpoint.

This post might be useful: [Should I build server-side of application inside nuxt.js server directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541191/should-i-build-server-side-of-application-inside-nuxt-js-server-directory)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your project. If you fetch your data directly from your laravel enddpoint there is no interest to fill and use the api folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is another benefit to the server directory.
All requests are made to the Nuxt server, which is located at the frontend address. For example, your frontend is located at http://www.example-front.com and your backend is http://www.example-backend.com, if you make a request to http://www.example-front.com/server/api/product/ and inside it make a request to your backend, then from the browser we will not see the real address of your server application, it helps to hide the API endpoint.
You can also format the response from your server to the type you need (for example, hide some fields) and now in the browser will see the formatted response

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).